# jQuery.validate() newbie: it doesn't work for me

Tags: jquery, validation

Im trying to validate an email field dynamically using jquery.validate [here](http://www.tirengarfio.com).

The field i'm speaking about is "Email" ("Registro" form).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Your script order is reversed, include jQuery *before* any plugins, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

Also since I don't see any conflicts, I'd go ahead and move to jQuery 1.4 to get the latest benefits.

Comment: I second this.  If you're ever using a script that requires jQuery (or any other library for that matter), ensure the library is loaded before the script so it has access to it.

Answer (score 0):

I failed inside the rule..This works ok:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() { alert("submitted!"); }
});

$().ready(function() {
    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#jander").validate({
        rules: {
            'sfApplyApply[email]': {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'sfApplyApply[email]': "Please enter an email",
        }
    });
});

</script>
```